# Kentico CMSForms in a live context

Tags: kentico

I created a cms form field would like to get the value of it at runtime from the codebehind of one of my template classes.  Is this possible?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:

```
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.OnlineForms;
using CMS.SiteProvider;.
...
...
...        
var formInfo = BizFormInfoProvider.GetBizFormInfo("ContactUs", SiteInfoProvider.GetSiteInfo("mySiteID").SiteID);
var className = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(formInfo.FormClassID).ClassName;
var data = BizFormItemProvider.GetItems(className);

if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(data))
{
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var myFieldValue = item.GetStringValue("MyFieldColumnName", "");
    }
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+form+data+using+the+API).